# Prevent ajax post when back button is pressed

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, browser

When the form is posted(ajax), I am navigating to other page and while pressing the back button, the form is again posted.

Is there any way to stop ajax post while clicking on back button in browser ?

I have used the below code to stop previous request, but after this back and forward button are disabled in the browser.

```
window.onpopstate = function (e) {}; history.pushState({}, '');
```

**NOTE:** I am getting this issue only in `chrome` and `safari`.

Comment: `onclick="history.back();event.preventDefault();"`

Comment: For which elements's onclick ?

Comment: for back button's onclick

Comment: This is best handled server-side.

Answer (score 1):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery/446626#446626) suggest suppose you have this ajax request

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: "name=John&location=Boston",
  success: function(msg) {
    alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
  }
});

window.onpopstate = function(e) {
  //kill the request
  xhr.abort()
};
history.pushState({}, '');
```